# CLI tools to test internet connectivity and stability

Tags: windows, linux, networking, internet

I have to choose between two Internet Service Providers (ISP's), I have tried ping to test the two ISP's but I am looking for more accurate and reliable testing tools.

Comment: I am not sure how you can test them until you have an account there.

Comment: @RohitGupta I have them both at my place, I just plug either WAN cable to the router. One ISP over cables and the other over wireless link.

Comment: You can use `curl` or `wget` commands to download or upload big file using both ISPs and compare speed and time. There are also number of CLI speedtests available if you search like https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

Answer (score 2):

Install speedtest-cli  `apt-get install speedtest-cli`

https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli